# Is a Markov chain sampled at stopping times a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chain

Given a Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ and $T_n$  an increasing sequence of stopping times, is $\{X_{T_n}\}$ a Markov chain ?

Comment: Is this a class exercise?

Comment: @Glen_b: No, I found it being used in a paper. Searched in the internet, did not find any such result.

Comment: Are you able to say which paper?

Comment: It all depends on how $(T_n)$ and $(X_n)$ are related.

Comment: I haven't looked at the paper, but are you sure it's not the strong Markov property?  i.e. $(X_{T_n + k})_{k\ge 0}$ is a Markov chain, conditional on $X_{T_n}$.

Comment: We had an essentially identical question recently. How does this question arise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $(X_n)_n$ an arbitrary ergodic Markov chain and define $T_n$ as
$$T_n=\min\{t>T_{n-1}\,;X_t\le 2X_{T_{n-1}}\,,X_t\ge X_{T_{n-2}}\}\,.$$(Let us assume that the conditions are met for $T_n$ to be almost surely finite!) Then $X_{T_n}$ is not independent of $X_{T_{n-2}}$ given $X_{T_{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have the recurrence relation

$T_{n+1} = T_{n} + Y$

where $Y$ is the first return time of the random variable. Try proceeding from here. I would recommend you go through the proofs you already have very carefully. (Please mark such questions as self study in the future)

Comment: Another tip: Suppose you hit $A$, coming from a state outside of $A$, in the state $X_{T_n} \in A$. Then does the future evolution of the chain depend on anything more than the fact you are now in that state?

Comment: @Sid: It should be $Y_n$, not just $Y$.